# Laravel 4 - Controller method not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I want to modify an user from the list. I have the codes in the routes.php:

```
Route::get('users/{all}/edit', 'UserController@getEdit');
Route::post('users/update', ['as' => 'users.postUpdate', 'uses' => 'UserController@postUpdate']);
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

In the UserController.php, I wrote the following script for edit and update:

```
public function getEdit($id)
{
    //

    $user = User::find($id);
    if (is_null($user))
        {

            return Redirect::to('users/all');
        }
    return View::make('users.edit', compact('user'));
}


/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function postUpdate($id)
{
    //


    $input = Input::all();
    $validation = Validator::make($input, User::$rules);
    if ($validation->passes())
    {
        //$user = User::find($id);

            $user = User::find($id);
            $user->username = Input::get('username');
            $user->name = Input::get('name');
            $user->email = Input::get('email');
            $user->phone = Input::get('phone');
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $user->save();

        return Redirect::route('users.getIndex', $id);
    }
    return Redirect::route('users.getEdit', $id)
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validation)
        ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
}
```

The code under edit.blade.php as below:

```
@extends('users.user') 

@section('main')

<h1>Edit User</h1>
{{ Form::model($user, array('method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => array('users.postUpdate', $user->id))) }}
<ul>
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('username', 'Username:') }}
        {{ Form::text('username') }}
    </li>
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('password', 'Password:') }}
        {{ Form::text('password') }}
    </li>
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email:') }}
        {{ Form::text('email') }}
    </li>
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('phone', 'Phone:') }}
        {{ Form::text('phone') }}
    </li>
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('name', 'Name:') }}
        {{ Form::text('name') }}
    </li>
    <li>
        {{ Form::submit('Update', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}
        {{ link_to_route('users.getAll', 'Cancel', $user->id, array('class' => 'btn')) }}
    </li>
</ul>
{{ Form::close() }}

@if ($errors->any())
<ul>
    {{ implode('', $errors->all('<li class="error">:message</li>')) }}
</ul>
@endif

@stop
```

The edit screen is opening well. However, when modify the values and submit the form, the URL shows as http://localhost/testlaravell/users/update?5 and the error occurs that -

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
Controller method not found.
```

Please help me how can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you use `PATCH` method but in Controller you have method `postUpdate` (and same for `routes.php`).

What you should probably do is:

- changing in controller method `postUpdate` to `putUpdate`
- changing

  ```
  Route::post('users/update', ['as' => 'users.postUpdate', 'uses' => 'UserController@postUpdate']);
  ```

  into

  ```
  Route::put('users/update/{id}', ['as' => 'users.putUpdate', 'uses' => 'UserController@putUpdate']);
  ```
- changing in your form

  ```
  {{ Form::model($user, array('method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => array('users.postUpdate', $user->id))) }
  ```

  into

  ```
  {{ Form::model($user, array('method' => 'PUT', 'route' => array('users.putUpdate', $user->id))) }
  ```

Comment: Another correct answer @Marcin. Thanks a lot. You're a Laravel Master.

Answer (score 0):

Define your route like this:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

Change it:

```
{{ Form::model($user, array('method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => array('users.postUpdate', $user->id))) }}
```

to

```
{!! Form::model($user, array('method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => array('users.update', $user->id))) !!}
```

Write your controller like this:

```
public function edit($id)
   {
       $user = User::find($id);
       if (is_null($user))
        {

            return Redirect::to('users/all');
        }
    return View::make('users.edit', compact('user'));
}


/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */

public function update($id)
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $validation = Validator::make($input, User::$rules);
    if ($validation->passes())
    {

            $user = User::find($id);
            $user->username = Input::get('username');
            $user->name = Input::get('name');
            $user->email = Input::get('email');
            $user->phone = Input::get('phone');
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $user->save();

        return Redirect::route('users.getIndex', $id);
    }
    return Redirect::route('users.getEdit', $id)
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validation)
        ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
}
```

Hope, it'll works.